# SQL Server - Comparing BIGINT to VARCHAR within query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 queries; 1, I manually run, which returns the top 5 projects, the other is a stored procedure which is executed and passes the resultset from the initial query in as a string parameter as part of its clause.

I'm getting an obvious error telling me I can't compare a BIGINT to a VARCHAR (which makes sense, as Im passing a string built from my resultset of the Project ID's I want it to return in the stored procedure), but for the life of me, can't think of a way around it.

Error:

> Error converting data type varchar to bigint

Query:

```
DECLARE @Projects AS VARCHAR(MAX) 

SET @Projects = (SELECT '''' + SUBSTRING((SELECT TOP 5 ''',' + '''' + CAST(Project_ID AS VARCHAR) AS 'data()' 
                                          FROM Project 
                                          WHERE ISNULL(Imported, 0) = 0 
                                          FOR XML PATH('')), 4 , 9999) + '''')

SELECT @Projects

EXEC TestSP @values = @Projects
```

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TestSP]
    @values AS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT Project
    FROM Budget 
    WHERE Budget.Project IN (@values)
END
```

The result set I get from my query is:

```
'5863 ','5875 ','5892 ','5899 ','5955'
```

How can I approach this from a different angle, as I've been bashing my head against it for the past couple of hours now and the logic feels rather simple.

Thanks

Comment: As you have discovered you can't pass a string like that to IN. You either have to use dynamic sql (not recommended) or find another approach. The best way by far for this is to use a [table valued parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Ah, thanks - suspected there had to be another approach! Table valued params sounds like it could be pretty handy. Do you know if I can do something akin to an IN using a table valued param in my SP clause?

Comment: You would simply join Budget to your table valued parameter. It is a parameter that behaves like a table.

Comment: Ahh - fantastic, thank's I'll give it a go